# Run Custom File Automatic Test In Azure Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have 6 unit test project but i wanna my `pipeline` just run some of this folder

for example

[image]

[image]

this `yaml` code run all tests but i dont want nop.data.tests ran in pipeline so
can i  just run all nop tests Except for nop.data

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify the patterns. See [File matching patterns reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops)

For example :

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\nop.data.tests.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  continueOnError: true
```